# Vanishing item with List Array Collection.shuffle?

Tags: android, collections, shuffle

I splitted to letters a word. And I mixed it. Every thing is ok until now. The problem in the logs. Why is a letter vanishing in the second log.

```
    String word ="windows";

    String[] un_mix = word.split(""); 
    String[] saw = word.split("");

    Log.i(TAG, "un_mix: "+saw[1]+saw[2]+saw[3]+saw[4]+saw[5]+saw[6]+saw[7]);

    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(saw));

    Collections.shuffle(stringList);

    saw = stringList.toArray(new String[stringList.size()]); 

    Log.i(TAG, Cls + "saw_mix: "+saw[0]+saw[1]+saw[2]+saw[3]+saw[4]+saw[5]+saw[6]);
    Log.i(TAG, Cls + "saw_mix2: "+saw[0]+saw[1]+saw[2]+saw[3]+saw[4]+saw[5]+saw[6]+saw[7]);
```

This is log record;

```
12-28 08:50:06.198 I/Maincls: un_mix: windows // How is it that, Why saw[0] is not necessary ?

12-28 08:50:06.210 I/Maincls: saw_mix: iwwnod // Why is a letter vanished ?

12-28 08:50:06.210 I/Maincls: saw_mix2: iwwnods // which one is saw[0] or saw[7] ?
```

Comment: I believe it's giving you an empty string in one of the array elements.  Put quotes around each one to see it.

Comment: `String[] saw = word.split("")` wiil be returning an **array with an empty string at 0th position** 
i.e = " windows"

Comment: Yes maybe. But I can't find the solution ??

Comment: Oo thanks. I found it.   stringList.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
        stringList.removeAll(Collections.singleton(""));